# In a Pandas DataFrame, how can the values for each day be normalized?

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that contains a set of values measured at different times. I want to normalize the values taken for each day to one. How can this be done?

To be specific, I have data of the following form:

```
                              value
datetime                           
2017-03-08 14:36:06.616166  1002.49
2017-03-08 15:06:07.661818   992.68
2017-03-08 15:36:08.597443   984.34
2017-03-08 16:06:09.265451   989.32
2017-03-08 16:36:10.581452  1004.00
2017-03-08 17:06:11.269434  1003.97
2017-03-08 17:36:12.117443   994.80
2017-03-08 18:06:12.809445   994.17
2017-03-08 18:36:14.029444   997.93
2017-03-08 19:06:14.654631   989.65
2017-03-08 19:36:15.413438   991.14
2017-03-08 20:06:16.145432   984.65
2017-03-08 20:36:17.265443   993.30
2017-03-08 21:06:18.117434   981.18
2017-03-08 21:36:19.165447   987.64
2017-03-08 22:06:19.909443   985.26
2017-03-08 22:36:20.569442   980.40
2017-03-08 23:06:21.197446   988.59
2017-03-08 23:36:21.989448   984.59
2017-03-09 00:06:22.665448   983.91
2017-03-09 00:36:23.281681   993.65
2017-03-09 01:06:23.857440   986.69
2017-03-09 01:36:24.441713   984.04
2017-03-09 02:06:25.117453   989.92
2017-03-09 02:36:25.953449   978.82
2017-03-09 03:06:26.521704   987.42
2017-03-09 03:36:27.157448   996.66
2017-03-09 04:06:27.725445   996.66
2017-03-09 04:36:29.201442   996.66
2017-03-09 05:06:29.765443   989.82
...                             ...
2017-03-22 20:16:24.007637   833.74
2017-03-22 20:46:24.583127   834.69
2017-03-22 21:16:25.217536   829.66
```

I want to normalize all of the values for 2017-03-08, 2017-03-09 etc. respectively and to add these normalized values as a new column.

A simple normalization function for a list of values is as follows:

```
def normalize(x, summation = None):
    if summation is None:
        summation = sum(x) # normalize to unity
    return [element/summation for element in x]
```

So, for 2017-03-08, the normalized values would be as follows:

```
                              value  value_day_normalized
datetime                                                 
2017-03-08 14:36:06.616166  1002.49  0.0532386976171
2017-03-08 15:06:07.661818   992.68  0.0527177232197
2017-03-08 15:36:08.597443   984.34  0.0522748153223
2017-03-08 16:06:09.265451   989.32  0.0525392855057
2017-03-08 16:36:10.581452  1004.00  0.0533188883755
2017-03-08 17:06:11.269434  1003.97  0.0533172951817
2017-03-08 17:36:12.117443   994.80  0.0528303089203
2017-03-08 18:06:12.809445   994.17  0.0527968518489
2017-03-08 18:36:14.029444   997.93  0.052996532148
2017-03-08 19:06:14.654631   989.65  0.0525568106383
2017-03-08 19:36:15.413438   991.14  0.0526359392674
2017-03-08 20:06:16.145432   984.65  0.0522912783257
2017-03-08 20:36:17.265443   993.30  0.0527506492265
2017-03-08 21:06:18.117434   981.18  0.0521069989007
2017-03-08 21:36:19.165447   987.64  0.0524500666486
2017-03-08 22:06:19.909443   985.26  0.0523236732678
2017-03-08 22:36:20.569442   980.40  0.0520655758599
2017-03-08 23:06:21.197446   988.59  0.052500517788
2017-03-08 23:36:21.989448   984.59  0.0522880919379
```

How can something like this be done? I have a feeling that it might involve use of the DataFrame method `groupby`, but I don't know how I should approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html)ide `Series` with same length as original `df` by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['value_day_normalized'] = df['value'].div(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['value']
                                               .transform('sum'))
print (df)
                             value  value_day_normalized
datetime                                                 
2017-03-08 14:36:06.616166  1002.49              0.053239
2017-03-08 15:06:07.661818   992.68              0.052718
2017-03-08 15:36:08.597443   984.34              0.052275
2017-03-08 16:06:09.265451   989.32              0.052539
2017-03-08 16:36:10.581452  1004.00              0.053319
2017-03-08 17:06:11.269434  1003.97              0.053317
2017-03-08 17:36:12.117443   994.80              0.052830
2017-03-08 18:06:12.809445   994.17              0.052797
2017-03-08 18:36:14.029444   997.93              0.052997
...
...
```

Another solution with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) and [`Resampler.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.transform.html):

```
df['value_day_normalized'] = df['value'].div(df.resample('D')['value'].transform('sum'))
print (df)
                              value  value_day_normalized
datetime                                                 
2017-03-08 14:36:06.616166  1002.49              0.053239
2017-03-08 15:06:07.661818   992.68              0.052718
2017-03-08 15:36:08.597443   984.34              0.052275
2017-03-08 16:06:09.265451   989.32              0.052539
2017-03-08 16:36:10.581452  1004.00              0.053319
2017-03-08 17:06:11.269434  1003.97              0.053317
2017-03-08 17:36:12.117443   994.80              0.052830
...
...
```